# Не передаются значения из html формы в FormData

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, formdata

Все данные, которые я передаю, даже если они заданы в явном виде, равны null, когда я пытаюсь их получить в сервлете

```
<form name="authorForm" id="authorForm" >
    <Label>Author (required)</Label>
    <input type="text" id="authorName" name="authorName"/>
    <label for="authorName" ></label>
    <Label>Author image></Label>
    <input type="file" id="authorImage" name="path" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg ">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="addAuthor" />
</form>
<div class="add" onclick="addAuthors()">Send</div>



async function addAuthors() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const form = document.getElementById( "authorForm" );
    const FD = new FormData(form);
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8081/Task1_war_exploded/main");
    xhr.send(FD);
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _функция не отправляет запрос_?

Comment: потому что в отладке запускала, я и не попадаю в сервлет

Comment: а почему ты должна была в него попасть?

Comment: отредактировала вопрос

Comment: проблема именно с get параметром в POST запросе?

Comment: это не твой случай? [httpServletRequest.getParameter returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844999/2881286)

Comment: мой запрос должен перехватываться сервлетом, но этого не происходит, когда в коде есть const FD = new FormData(form); без этой строки запрос срабатывает, если передавать что-то другое

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133028/discussion-between-grundy-and-mak).